# Extract data of table with webscraping python 2

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

I need to extract data of table from web  with websraping python 2.7
i have this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json 
import pandas as pd                     
from urllib import urlopen
import requests
import re
from IPython.display import Image
PRODUIT= []
CAS = []
Ref_Catalogue = []
Quantite = []
Prix_HT = []
client = requests.Session()
HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.scbt.com/scbt/fr/browse/chemicals-Research-Reagents-by-Application-Tyrosine-Kinase-Inhibitors/_/N-118tblu'
html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
soup = soup(html)
cont = soup.find("table", {"class":"table plp-table table-hover"})
cont2 = cont.find("tbody")
#tr = cont2.find("tr")
for contk in cont2:
    tr = contk.find("tr")
    print tr
#print tr
############################################
#print col
columns = {'PRODUIT': PRODUIT, 'CAS': CAS, 'Ref_Catalogue': Ref_Catalogue, 'Quantite': Quantite, 'Prix_HT': Prix_HT}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
df
```

but I got this results

```
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-
```

I need to extract data from table ?
how I can extract PRODUIT': PRODUIT, 'CAS': CAS, 'Ref_Catalogue': Ref_Catalogue, 'Quantite': Quantite, 'Prix_HT': Prix_HT
thhnx for all

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Run the script and I hope you will get the data you were after.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.scbt.com/scbt/fr/browse/chemicals-Research-Reagents-by-Application-Tyrosine-Kinase-Inhibitors/_/N-118tblu')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
for items in soup.select(".table tr"):
    data = ' '.join([' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select("th,td")[:-2]])
    print(data.strip())
```

I've written this code compatible to python 3. So you may need to apply some minor changes to fit for python 2.7.